# How exactly works the MySql unique constraint defined on a nullable field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, rdbms

I am not so into database (I am using **MySql) and I have the following doubt about the **unique** constraint **setted on a nullable field**

So from what I know the UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are different.

But what happens if I set a unique constraint on a nullable field of a table.

For example I have this **DDL** table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  id        BigInt UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  sample_id VarChar(128) NOT NULL,
  doi       VarChar(128),
  result    VarChar(2) NOT NULL,
  error     Text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ;
ALTER TABLE results COMMENT = '';
ALTER TABLE results ADD CONSTRAINT fk_results_pgrfas FOREIGN KEY (sample_id)
  REFERENCES pgrfas (sample_id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
ALTER TABLE results ADD CONSTRAINT u_results UNIQUE 
    (doi);
```

where the **doi** field is nullable. On this field is setted the unique constraint because I want prevent that more rows of this table have the same values of the **doi** field.

Each rows needs to have a different **doi** values but this field can be null so I need to have that multiple rows have the **doi** field setted to null.

The unique constraint works only on setted values or also prevent that differents rows have **null** value for this **doi** field? (this will be a problem for me because I need that the unique constraint only works on not null values).

So can I insert multiple rows having the **doi** field setted to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is buried deep in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) for `create index`:

> A `UNIQUE` index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. **For all engines, a `UNIQUE`
>   index permits multiple `NULL` values for columns that can contain `NULL`.**

Note that this behavior varies among databases.  Some allow only one `NULL` value.

For your purpose, the `unique` index/constraint does just what you need.

Comment: Think of it this way:  `NULL` is not equal to _anything_, including another `NULL`.  So, it is logical that there could be lots of `NULL` values in "unique" index.

Comment: @RickJames . . . That is not a good line of reasoning.  Some databases allow multiple `NULL` values; some do not.  It is just something you have to remember (or remember to look up), such as whether or not the database does integer division.